# Is there any resource (PDF or Videos serires) on lotus domino application development

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I need a book reference or video course reference on lotus domino development (application development).

Comment: Did you search on youtube ?

Comment: yes, @PeterMmm i have tried youtube but it's only introductory material, not detailed like others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about web applications rather than noted client applications. These are some very  useful sites:

David Leedy has published many many videos around the whole topic of XPages app dev:
http://www.notesin9.com/

Open source community around IBM domino app dev:
https://openntf.org/main.nsf

IBM Domino Application Development Wiki:
https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/m_Home.xsp#mobileCategoryList

XPages chest sheets (also David keedy‘s work):
http://xpagescheatsheet.com/

IBM published a few books (packt publishing):
Mastering XPages
XPages Extension Library

There is a lot more around , I find these particularly helpful.

There is a vivid community available with many user groups, blogs etc. 
http://planetlotus.org/ is a good starting point to check out what is going ...

HTH!

Comment: thank you, i am specifically looking for noted client applications development.